# Abbreviations for "gerund", "gerundive" and "supine"?

Tags: terminology, latin, interlinear-gloss, notation

Are there some commonly used abbreviations for "gerund", "gerundive" and "supine"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two of those are listed on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_glossing_abbreviations):SUP for supine, (use SUPL for superlative if both terms will be employed in one work) and GER for gerund. Neither is found in the [Leipzig Glossing Conventions](http://grammar.ucsd.edu/courses/lign120/leipziggloss.pdf), which is fast becoming a standard in linguistics. [Lehmann (1982)](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/flin.1982.16.issue-1-4/flin.1982.16.1-4.199/flin.1982.16.1-4.199.xml) contains a suggestion only for gerund (GER). [An undated though recent paper](http://www.ling.hawaii.edu/ldtc/website/syllabus/sp06/LehmannGlossing.pdf) apparently by C. Lehmann suggests OBLG for gerundive with the note ("use obligative").

Answer (score 1):

Looking up the parameter [VerbForm in the Index Thomisticus treebank in Universal Dependencies](http://universaldependencies.org/treebanks/la_ittb/la_ittb-feat-VerbForm.html) I find *Ger* for Gerund, *Gdv* for Gerundive, but a tag for Supinum is missing.The [PROIEL treebank](http://universaldependencies.org/treebanks/la_proiel/la_proiel-feat-VerbForm.html) has *Sup* for Supine (for strange reasons, only the Supine in *-u* is found there).